# Any way to use a Firebird embedded database on a native (NDK) Android app?

Tags: android, android-ndk, firebird

I'm looking at migrating a Windows program to Android.  It uses a local Firebird database with `fbembed.dll`.

I've looked around the Internet and run a few searches, but the only Firebird clients I've found for Android are JDBC drivers.  But this isn't particularly useful to me, since I'm using native code.

Is anyone aware of any way to access a Firebird database natively on Android?

Comment: There have been a few threads on the Firebird development mailinglist to get Firebird to compile for Android. I believe there were some problems, but I don't know if anyone got it working or not. You might want to start a thread there: see https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/firebird-devel for subscribing.